# Modelling Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, data-modeling, azure-cosmosdb

I'm planning on saving records from [CoinMarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) for own purpose.
I would like to save price information on the top 100 crypto coins every 15 minutes, and I would like to save it in an Azure Cosmos DB.

Since im new to the whole concept of document db's, I need some help modelling the documents.

First I started out with this model.

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "rank": "1",
        "price_usd": "573.137",
        "price_btc": "1.0",
        "24h_volume_usd": "72855700.0",
        "market_cap_usd": "9080883500.0",
        "available_supply": "15844176.0",
        "total_supply": "15844176.0",
        "percent_change_1h": "0.04",
        "percent_change_24h": "-0.3",
        "percent_change_7d": "-0.57",
        "last_updated": "1472762067"
    },
    {
        "id": "ethereum",
        "name": "Ethereum",
        "symbol": "ETH",
        "rank": "2",
        "price_usd": "12.1844",
        "price_btc": "0.021262",
        "24h_volume_usd": "24085900.0",
        "market_cap_usd": "1018098455.0",
        "available_supply": "83557537.0",
        "total_supply": "83557537.0",
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.58",
        "percent_change_24h": "6.34",
        "percent_change_7d": "8.59",
        "last_updated": "1472762062"
    },
    ...
]
```

But since id did not change every time I wrote to the DB, the records was only updated, and not aggregated. I guess this was as expected.

So in order to make sure the records were aggregated, I rewrote the model to this.

```
[
    {
        "id": <timestamp>_bitcoin
        "identifier": "bitcoin",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "rank": "1",
        "price_usd": "573.137",
        "price_btc": "1.0",
        "24h_volume_usd": "72855700.0",
        "market_cap_usd": "9080883500.0",
        "available_supply": "15844176.0",
        "total_supply": "15844176.0",
        "percent_change_1h": "0.04",
        "percent_change_24h": "-0.3",
        "percent_change_7d": "-0.57",
        "last_updated": "1472762067"
    },
    {
        "id": <timestamp>_ethereum
        "identifier": "ethereum",
        "name": "Ethereum",
        "symbol": "ETH",
        "rank": "2",
        "price_usd": "12.1844",
        "price_btc": "0.021262",
        "24h_volume_usd": "24085900.0",
        "market_cap_usd": "1018098455.0",
        "available_supply": "83557537.0",
        "total_supply": "83557537.0",
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.58",
        "percent_change_24h": "6.34",
        "percent_change_7d": "8.59",
        "last_updated": "1472762062"
    },
    ...
]
```

Here I added an separate `id` with an timestamp and reference to the old id in order to make it unique.

This is working okay, but I think it is some duplicate data (ex. name and symbol) which I think looks bad having double. But maybe this is how it is in the document db world?

I also thought about a model like this.

```
[
    {
        "id": <timestamp>_bitcoin
        "identifier": "bitcoin",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "rank": "1",
        "price_history": [{
            "price_usd": "573.137",
            "price_btc": "1.0",
            "24h_volume_usd": "72855700.0",
            "market_cap_usd": "9080883500.0",
            "available_supply": "15844176.0",
            "total_supply": "15844176.0",
            "percent_change_1h": "0.04",
            "percent_change_24h": "-0.3",
            "percent_change_7d": "-0.57",
            "last_updated": "1472762067"
        ]}
    },
    {
        "id": <timestamp>_ethereum
        "identifier": "ethereum",
        "name": "Ethereum",
        "symbol": "ETH",
        "rank": "2",
        "price_history": [{
            "price_usd": "12.1844",
            "price_btc": "0.021262",
            "24h_volume_usd": "24085900.0",
            "market_cap_usd": "1018098455.0",
            "available_supply": "83557537.0",
            "total_supply": "83557537.0",
            "percent_change_1h": "-0.58",
            "percent_change_24h": "6.34",
            "percent_change_7d": "8.59",
            "last_updated": "1472762062"
        ]}
    },
    ...
]
```

But as there is no option to add new records to `price_history` without rewriting the whole document, this would not be a good idea. Also since the number of records in `price_history` would be potententially grow without limits, this document would get really big and hard to handle.

Next I think of splitting into separate documents, but not sure if that is the way to go either. So I'm a bit lost at the moment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirements for aggregating pricing information (if any) per cryptocurrency? Or is it that you just have to record the percent change over the last hour, day, and week per timestamp?

Comment: I would like to keep historic data in order to analyze it. An example would be to go back in time to check impact of news on price change, or other similar scenarios. Would also like to play with Azure Machine Learning, and in order to use that I need some data to analyze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the fact portion:

1. Having a single document per crypto-coin and embedding pricing information within the document in 15 minute intervals is not workable. Cosmos DB has a 2MB document size limit. You will blow through that size limit if you pursue an embed strategy. Also, you are right that larger documents are more difficult to work with and incur higher RU charges to retrieve.
2. In NoSQL in general, duplication of data is not necessarily a cardinal sin. You need to think about how data will be retrieved and what information you need to work with. This is especially important since there aren't relational joins as exists in relational DBs.

Now for the completely opinion part:

- Consider a crypto-coin document that contains general information about each coin you need to track. You may not actually even need this document.
- Store time series data as separate documents. You actually have to go this way due to the aforementioned document size limitation, and that there is no upper bound on the number of timestamp readings.
- For your 1 hour, 24 hour, and 7 day lookback aggregations that are stored as part of each timestamp, you may just query using aggregation functions and set these properties per timestamp each time you write a new entry. Given that you're only storing 100 different crypto-currencies and your timestamps are every 15 minutes, this is feasible.

[There's a great video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P468) on Channel 9 by Ryan CrawCour and David Makogon that deals with modeling data in Cosmos DB that I found very helpful when getting my head around this.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I have pretty much come to the same conclusion, and will look into having one document for crypto info, and a document collection for all of the price snapshots, with a separate document for each snapshot. Will also look at the video, great tip!

Comment: I think it is covered in the Channel 9 video, but you can also use a hybrid model: keep the single summary document and many time series price documents as Rob describes. But, also write the last x (say, 10) time series documents as a nested array in the summary document.

Comment: @MichaelFinger, that is an excellent point in general. It does take a little bookkeeping to accomplish though. Given the speed of document retrieval and the fact that each time series entry will be immutable after the lookback metrics are calculated, I don't know if it's necessary in this case.

Comment: I now have two collections, and in the ticker collection I keep the last price history record, so that I can always just query one document for the current price information. And if I need history, all the historic data is stored in a separate collection.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good article summarizing the best practices for data modeling in non-relational world https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data

HTH